# JAVA ClassCastException on foreach loop

Tags: java, exception, iterator

Im getting a weird behaviour iterating over an arraylist of a class that i made.

The class is this simple inmutable thing:

```
public class Social {
    private String url;
    private SocialNames cat;

    public Social(String url, SocialNames cat) {
        this.url = url;
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public SocialNames getCat() {
        return cat;
    }
}
```

The main program class which contains the arraylist goes something like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Data {
    private String facebook;
    private String twitter;
    private String google_plus;

    private ArrayList<Social> rrss = new ArrayList<Social>();

    public Data() {
    }

    private void parse() {
        //This function is way more complicated in the real code
        //But i think it doesn't interact with rrss

        facebook = "http://www.facebook.com/";
        twitter = "http://www.twitter.com/";
        google_plus = "http://www.google.com/";
    }

    public void load(String data) {
        parse();
        composeRRSS();
        dumpResults();       
    }

    private void dumpResults() {  
        for (Social s: rrss) {
            System.out.println("SOCIAL: "+s.getCat() + " URL="+s.getUrl());
        }        
    }

    private void composeRRSS() {
        if (facebook != null && !facebook.isEmpty()) {
            rrss.add(new Social(facebook, SocialNames.FACEBOOK));
        }

        if (twitter != null && !twitter.isEmpty()) {
            rrss.add(new Social(twitter, SocialNames.TWITTER));  
        }

        if (google_plus != null && !google_plus.isEmpty()) {
            rrss.add(new Social(google_plus, SocialNames.GOOGLE_PLUS));            
        }
    }
}
```

SocialNames is just an enum like:

FACEBOOK, TWITTER, GOOGLE_PLUS

When i call `load()` i get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to quickproject.Social

at quickproject.Data.dumpResults(Data.java:252)
    at quickproject.Data.load(Data.java:234)
    at quickproject.QuickProject.load(QuickProject.java:413)
    at quickproject.QuickProject.access$700(QuickProject.java:55)
    at quickproject.QuickProject$13.actionPerformed(QuickProject.java:443)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:842)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:886)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I dont have any idea of what is failing here, rrss is clearly an arraylist of Social objects, even wierder is that i in the Data class i have another function which does:

```
for (Social s: rrss) {
    switch(s.getCat()) {
        case FACEBOOK:
            sb.append("<facebook>").append(s.getUrl()).append("</facebook>").append(System.lineSeparator());
            break;
        case TWITTER:
            sb.append("<twitter>").append(s.getUrl()).append("</twitter>").append(System.lineSeparator());                    
            break;
        case GOOGLE_PLUS:
            sb.append("<google_plus>").append(s.getUrl()).append("</google_plus>").append(System.lineSeparator());
            break;
    }
}
```

and it does work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Have a nice day.

[EDIT]

SocialNames code:

```
public enum SocialNames {
    FACEBOOK, TWITTER, GOOGLE_PLUS;
}
```

Comment: Can you debug your program and inspect exactly what is actually in that arraylist? Because it sounds like it's got strings in it.

Comment: @DushyantTankariya i have edited the question to include SocialNames class.

Comment: @khelwood it shows one string "\r\n" how is that possible? The array is only declared before the constructor and the only add call there are are thoose three in the compose function

Comment: Then your problem isn't the cast: it's finding out how you got that string into your list. What you have included in your question is not a [mre] I can't say from this how that's happening.

Comment: @khelwood there was a lot of obscure code in that parse function, with that hint of "there may be an string getting in the way" i figured out what happened, the rrss field was being aletered by a reflected field over an unchecked condition. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You should rewrite this

```
 System.out.println("SOCIAL: "+s.getCat() + " URL="+s.getUrl());
```

to this

```
 System.out.println("SOCIAL: "+s.getCat().name() + " URL="+s.getUrl());
```

Comment: Unclear how this is relevant to the exception that the OP is asking about.

Comment: This was actually a good guess based on provided information, but OP did not give enough information to answer this question.